# Need support to generate a word document using StringBuilder

Tags: c#, html, stringbuilder

I'm trying to generate a word document using `StringBuilder`, as follows

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void ExportToWord(string HTMLContent)
    {

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        string strFileName = "GenerateDocument" + ".doc";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);
        System.Text.StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        strHTMLContent.Append(HTMLContent);


        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();         
    }
```

The problem is when i see the downloaded doc, it has the remaining page content added with the above `<div>` content

Answer (score 2):

I'm missing a `Response.Clear` at the beginning  and `Response.End()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As i'm calling the `ExportToWord()` using `jquery` how can i create the doc in this case. please see the edited code.